# Read CSV file in A linked List Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to implement a static-public method named "csvToList" in the class "Functionality.java". The method gets a string as input parameter and returns a LinkedList<String[]>.

Signature: csvToList(String path) : LinkedList<String[]>

The method reads a CSV file in the path. Each single line is divided into two parts. The two parts are always separated by a comma. The two parts are normalized by removing any spaces at the front and back, and stored in a string array. This two-pair in string[] is added to the list. The list with the two-pairs is to be returned.

The algorithm must meet the following requirements:

The first row should not be read in, because it contains only the column information.
The normalized entries of a line should be in a string array.
The individual elements of the lines should not contain any spaces in the string array.
If an IOException is thrown when reading the file, null should be returned. Use try & catch for this.
My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.LinkedList
public class Functionality{
public static LinkedList<String[]> csvToList(String path) {

    LinkedList<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        
        br.lines()
        .filter(line -> br.getLineNumber() > 1)
        .forEach(line -> {

        String[] fields = path.split(",");

        String mail = fields[0].trim();
        String password = fields[1].trim();
        String[] csv = { mail, password };

        list.add(csv);

        br.close();

        return list;

        } catch (IOException e) {   
        return null;
    }
    
    }
}
```

}

The CSV-File:

```
Mail,Passwort
sam@gmail.com, sfkjiwefsdkfl
totin@airbnb.com, 29sdf@s
raj@gmail.com, abc
dev@gmail.com, wild
```

Is there a better way to implement the algorithm

Comment: well, you could use try-with-resources instead to avoid having to call `close` explicitly, and also handle the error case correctly (you currently don't close `br` in case of an `IOException`).

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment, follow the advice in the answer below and use a csv reader library. Also note that there is [`Stream.skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip(long)) to skip the first `n` entries in a stream.

Comment: @Hulk it is a homework assignment and we only learn the Buffered Reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to implement a static-public method named "csvToList" in the class "Functionality.java". The method gets a string as input parameter and returns a LinkedList<String[]>.

Uh, why?

LinkedList is almost invariably a mistake. It's slow as molasses. Not just algorithmically, LinkedList tends to be slow even if, theoretically, it should be fast: Because it makes tracker objects it just does all the things that you should not be doing on CPUs where all memory access goes through cache pages (and **all** modern CPUs work that way). Also, mixing generics and arrays is a grave mistake. It 'works', but causes friction all over the place. Unreadable code that is hard to test and write correctly.

This should be making perhaps a `List<List<String>>`. Certainly not `String[]` and certainly not `LinkedList`, in any case.

> `new FileReader(path)`

No, don't do that. This uses 'platform default charset encoding'. You don't want that. Use the new file API, which is easier to use and defaults to UTF-8.

> The method reads a CSV file in the path.

Actually, nevermind that. Reading CSV is far more complicated than you seem to think it is. It certainly is far more complicated than what `split` can do for you. Use CSV reader libraries like such as [SuperCSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html). CSVs can include quotes, multiline strings, and more.

> ```
> } catch (IOException e) {   
>    return null;
> }
> ```

Don't do this. Ignoring errors is not something you should do lightly. If you don't have a good idea about to do with errors, `throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);` is what you want in your catch block.

Comment: You said "Uh, why?" ask my professor :) he love linked list. I go through your text and corrected my error. We only learn the BufferedReader to do this

Comment: LinkedList is like a secret handshake. It screams 'academia!'. Profs love it. Java code written for dollars or eyeballs (vs. for learning things) basically never uses them.